# React native and ionic third party secret keys

Tags: angular, reactjs, react-native, ionic2

How can i secure my third party secret keys in react native and ionic?
i saved my secret keys in .env files in react native with 'react-native-config' package. is it secure?
and how can we secure secret keys in ionic2 or angualr2 application

Comment: I have the same question :)

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1093